# If statement Jquery to set width

Tags: jquery

I want a image with `class="thumb"` get `width:100%` if its width is greater than 400px

I tried this one but not working

```
   if ($(".thumb").width() > '400px')
{
  $(".thumb").css{("width","100%")}
}
```

Comment: `.width()` will return numeric value not `px` with it :) see [API](http://api.jquery.com/width/), For clear understanding look for the difference between `.width()` and css({'width':'..'})`

Answer (score 1):

`width()` returns a numeric. Try:

```
if ($(".thumb").width() > 400)
{
  $(".thumb").css("width","100%")
}
```

instead. As an alternative to a JavaScript-based solution, if you are trying to use responsive design techniques here you can also use media queries within CSS; they will allow you to set the width to 100% automatically when the page-width falls below a certain value, for example:

```
@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .thumb {
    width: 400px;
  }
}
```

(Note that this assumes .thumb has other HTML elements around it, and so this only needs to trigger when the page itself reaches 600 pixels wide.)

Comment: Thanks for an extra advice.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a comparison with string. You should compare it with a number because `.width()` returns number

try

```
if ($(".thumb").width() > 400)
```

Edit:

Just noticed, there is an error in the following line

```
 $(".thumb").css{("width","100%")}
```

The curly braces are used incorrectly. Remove them.  use the following code

```
$(".thumb").css("width", "100%");
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok noone got it so far? hehe

You have to

- reverse the < to >
- remove the brackets from css
- add a semicolon
- and also give a numeric value to your comparison

so its like this:

```
if ($(".thumb").width() > 400)
{
  $(".thumb").css("width","100%");
}
```

Comment: @user2417528 No worries ;)

Answer (score 1):

Please check http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/87/

```
if ($(".thumb").width() < 400){
    $(".thumb").css("width","100%");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set **>** sign instead of the **<** also need to remove a "px" from the comparison because .width() return number

```
if ($(".thumb").width() > 400)
{
  $(".thumb").css{("width","100%")}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try < '400'. remove the 'px'

Answer (score 0):

try without `{` and `}` you don't need this 2 chars.